# Error when running a Tabula commend to read pdf file

Tags: dataframe, tabula, tabula-py, python-3.12

I have to read pdf files and extract data from them. Im trying to use Tabula. I created a `venv`(virtual environment) in my folder where all the pdf files are. Activated my `venv` and installed Tabula using the below command.

```
pip3 install tabula-py
```

Imported Tabula in my file and it works fine.
However, when I try and read the pdf file,

```
table = tabula.read_pdf("somefilename", pages="all")
```

It give me this error,

```
Got stderr: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
```

Really need to get around this, any ideas?

Im not sure what to do.